# Wget 503 unavailable error

Tags: web-scraping, wget

```
$ wget www.amazon.com
Resolving www.amazon.com... 205.251.242.54
Connecting to www.amazon.com|205.251.242.54|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2015-10-12 23:27:24 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

I am trying to issue `wget` on a URL and getting this error. I need to store the HTML files and I was hoping wget would work :(

I tried using the `--no-proxy` option but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can issue `wget http://www.amazon.com` without any problem.
My guess is that you got blocked by amazon after scrapping a little bit to much...

**503 Service Unavailable**

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.
>
> ```
>   Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a
>   server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish
>   to simply refuse the connection.
> ```

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Is there a better way to do than wget?

Comment: You can try `curl`, `php curl`, `python urllib2`, `java jsoup`, etc.. and set a `user agent` on your request, rotating proxies may also help you.

Comment: Another thing to try could be adding sleep statements between your wget commands. They might not like you making so many requests per second (or per minute, or per hour, whatever, but adding `sleep 1s` will cut down your requests per second & minute by a lot)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that amazon firewall is blocking connections whose user-agent is not set, or incorrect.

You may try setting user agent to wget and get amazon with following command (note that you may need to change a valid user agent if this one becomes invalid):

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.79 Safari/537.36" https://amazon.com
```